# how to remove key value from map in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, playframework, scala-collections

```
Map(data -> "sumi", rel -> 2, privacy -> 0, status -> 1,name->"govind singh")
```

how to remove data from this map , if privacy is 0.

```
Map(rel -> 2, privacy -> 0, status -> 1,name->"govind singh")
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you use immutable maps, you can use the `-` method to create a new map without the given key:

```
val mx = Map("data" -> "sumi", "rel" -> 2, "privacy" -> 0)

val m = mx("privacy") match {
    case 0 => mx - "data"
    case _ => mx
}

=> m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(rel -> 2, privacy -> 0)
```

If you use mutable maps, you can just remove a key with either `-=` or `remove`.

Comment: You don't have to use pattern matching here because if there is no key which you are removing from existing Map it returns the same Map.
No errors.

Answer (score 26):

If you're looking to scale this up and remove multiple members, then `filterKeys` is your best bet:

```
val a = Map(
  "data"    -> "sumi",
  "rel"     -> "2",
  "privacy" -> "0",
  "status"  -> "1",
  "name"    -> "govind singh"
)

val b = a.filterKeys(_ != "data")
```

Comment: This retains reference to the filtering collection not allowing it to be garbage collected.

Comment: Building off of @St.Antario's comment, `filterKeys` results in a map that cannot be serialized. So, if you are filtering a map that you plan on using as a Spark `Broadcast`, this approach will not work. In these cases, you are better off with something like the following: `valuesToRemove.foldLeft(theMap) { (filteredMap, valueToRemove) => filteredMap - valueToRemove }`

Answer (score 11):

That depends on the type of Scala.collection Map you are using. Scala comes with both `mutable` and `immutable` Maps. Checks these links:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map

and

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map

In both types of maps, `-` is usually the operation to remove a key. The details depend on the type of map. A `mutable` map can be modified in place by using `-=`. Something like

```
if (m.contains("privacy") && m.getOrElse("privacy", 1) == 0) {
    m -= "play"
}
```

On the other hand, an immutable map can not be modified in place and has to return a new map after removing an element.

```
if (m.contains("privacy") && m.getOrElse("privacy", 1) == 0) {
    val newM = m - "play"
}
```

Notice that you are creating a new immutable map.

Answer (score 0):

```
val m = Map("data" -> "sumi", "rel" -> 2, "privacy" -> 0,"status" -> 1,"name"->"govind singh")
scala> if(m("privacy")==0) m.filterKeys(_ != "data")
res63: Any = Map(name -> govind singh, rel -> 2, privacy -> 0, status -> 1)
```